# Using rails data collection in .js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a books index page which shows all books using the familiair structure:

```
@books.each do |book|
 ....
end
```

On the same page I want to show a Google Chart, using the same `@books` data.
The chart is triggered by a div:

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

And there is a `chart.js.erb` file:

```
if ($("#chart_div").length > 0){
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Title', 'Author'],
      <%- @books.each do |book| %>
        <%= "['#{book.title}','#{book.author}']," %>
      <%- end %>
    ]);

    var chart = new     google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

But this returns the error `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`, so the`@books`is not available in the`.js.erb` file. How can I make the books available in the JavaScript? And are there better options to use this data in the chart?

Comment: Can you try putting up this chart generation javascript code into your index.html.erb

Comment: Are you defining `@books` properly in your container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScripts are not compiled in the context of controller action therefore you cannot use instance variables assigned in controller. You have possibly two options:

1. Load data via `AJAX` from the server from your `chart.js` file
2. Store `@book` data into your DOM during page rendering eg. as `JSON` and then read it from the `chart.js`

Second option is a little bit easier to explain:

Add code something like this to your page with cart:

```
<script id="chart_data" type="application/json" charset="uff-8>
  <%= raw @books.map { |book| [h(book.title), h(book.author)] }.unshift(['Title', 'Author']).to_json %>
</script>
```

And to your `draw_chart` function in `chart.js` load data with

```
var data_array = JSON.parse($("#chart_data").html());
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_array);
```

You can also remove `erb` extension from `chart.js` you will not need to compile javascripts with `erb`.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, your second option is great. The advantage over option 1 is that I can send `@books` data even when the filters on the page are used.